How to use Spacy-PyTextRank in newer versions?
I'm trying to do key phrase extraction with TextRank, I have installed 3.3.0 version, nltk and the en_core_web_trf are on 3.7.3, i dont know if this is the problem.
This is the error that I got
import pytextrank
nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')
nlp.add_pipe("textrank")

  [E002] Can't find factory for 'textrank' for language English (en).

I'm using spacy for cuda on windows wsl ubuntu in a notebook
I tried to downgrade the versions, reinstalling all, calling directly the pipe(but says its deprecated) and using the efficiency core

On a macOS laptop or an Ubuntu Linux server, this runs correctly with the code:
import spacy
import pytextrank

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
nlp.add_pipe("textrank")

doc = nlp("the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.")

for tok in doc:
    print(tok)

Using:

en_core_web_trf-3.7.3
spacy==3.7.5
pytextrank==3.3.0

Results:
the
quick
brown
fox
jumped
over
the
lazy
dog
.

You mentioned about about installing nltk though you probably meant spaCy ?
There is the difference of running with CUDA on Windows, although we haven't seen a "Can't find factory..." error before.  FWIW, I'm lead committer on the pytextrank project.
Would you mind opening a GitHub issue for this on https://github.com/DerwenAI/pytextrank/issues so we can track the issue and get more of our dev community involved?
